# hook click counter to each products

Tags: jquery

Im using wordpress

I have a jquery click counter, this code works. I'm planning to put the id tag of this code inside the div of the quick view button, because quick view button doesn't have view counts.

how can I hook this code to each products? it will be too mess up to input and this jquery code one by one to 100 products or more. Like post view counter.

```
var counter = 0;

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#addMe").click(function(){
                counter++;

                $("#theCount").text(counter);
            });

        });

div id="theCount"></div>
<button id="addMe">Add 1</button>
```

Comment: You can bind an event to multiple elements by writing a selector that selects more than one thing, such as `$('.view').click(function(){});`.  That will bind an event to *all* elements with `class="view"`.

Answer (score 0):

by changing this from id tag into class name, will this count for each product?

For example: product A, it has it's own click counter. Product B has it's own counter.

Will this work by just changing into classname?

Comment: it doesn't work , you just gave me on how to substitute from id tag into classname